# How to ingest comma separated csv with unquoted commas in some columns in ADF

Tags: azure, csv, data-cleaning, azure-data-factory

Hi everyone I have not seen this particular issue pop up, I've seen a few related but none address this.

I have very big CSVs (up to 8gb) with comma as delimiter, free text in some columns, and commas in some of that free text.

As requirements, I cannot generate or ask for the CSVs to be generated again with another delimiter, and I have to use Data Flow to achieve this.

I would like to learn how to deal with text such as:

```
A, some text 2132,ALL, free text 00001,2020-11-29 - 2020-12-05
A, some text 2132,ALL, free text\,more text 0002,2018-12-09 - 2018-12-15
A, some text 2132,ALL, free text\,more text 00003,2018-12-09 - 2018-12-15
```

Things I have tried:

- I tried making both simple Data Flows and Copy Activities in order to see if the parser did the operation properly, which it did not, didn't matter what combination of configuration of dataset as csv I tried.
- I tried reading the whole csv as one column, writing to file with the "," regexed out, this has the issue of "losing" the commas from the csv so I have spaces as delimiter so I am back to square one, not having a proper delimiter, since text has spaces and would break.

Comment: It's very unfortunate, but you have already ruled out the best two possible solutions to your problem. You said Data Flow is not an option, but in your "things I have tried" you said Data Flows. FTR - Data Flow could help here tremendously.

Comment: Regardless, if you have the ability to preprocess the data as you indicated, you could replace '\,' with some innocuous symbol like '|'. Then after you sink the data (you didn't say where this was going) you could apply a postprocess that replaces '|' with ',' to restore it.

Comment: The Parse transformation and Derived Column transformation in data flows would make this easy. I wonder why you can't use that activity?

Comment: What's the target database?  Azure SQL DB, Azure Synapse Analytics?  Thing is, it is possible to code around this type of thing but is it really worth the effort if, as the others have pointed out, the best thing to do is use a delimiter which does not otherwise occur in the text?  It's a fundamental design flaw to use comma where comma can occur in the free text column.  I've seen double-dagger (‡ Alt+0135) used for this for example.

Comment: I mistranslated myself. I wanted to say that I HAVE to use Data Flow. Did not remember English doesn't do well with double negations, my bad :(  MarkKromerMSFT @JoelCochran

Comment: @wBob Target it to write to disk as parquet to make it easier to work with this amount of data, in order to keep cleaning and operating with the same data as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, data factory can't deal with the csv file which column data have the character same with column delimiter. It will cause the schema/column missing.
Even with Data Flow, Data Factory will always recognize the first row as the schema according the delimiter number.

As you said you can't change the source csv file and can't use data flow. then I'm afraid to say I we can't achieve it in Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for this to work (did it it twice with different results so I am still missing things, but one of them it worked).

Create a dataset with no delimiter, so the whole CSV row is read as a column. Use dataflow replace function there to make the problematic string dissapear. Write to disk as CSV.

Read as CSV with proper delimiter. Do whatever data needs done, write to disk as parquet. That appears to work.

Comment: This is exactly what I was originally going to suggest, glad you got it working.

Comment: @JoelCochran thank you!! It's really nice to get confirmation what I did was not some dirty hack and instead a valid option, kind of.

Comment: Ok so apparently this no longer works. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome @JoelCochran, since different executions are giving different results. Now when I reread the csv (which has each row quoted, for no apparent reason), it's reading it as a single column, making all other columns to default to null.